# jQuery - Variable selectors in ForEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I've written a forEach loop which goes through an array of divs (by ID), selects child elements with a certain class and removes another class from them. I'm having a few issues turning the variable back into a selector and joining it to the other ones. As a result, my forEach loop doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/NWmB5/7/ (Try clicking one of the links, the third item should turn black again if the code works)

```
var toDoCategories; 

$(document).ready(function() {

toDoCategories = [$("#testDiv"),$("#anotherDiv"),$("thirdDiv")]; 
setTimelinePosition($('#thirdDiv'));

$('#targetFirstDiv').click(function() {
setTimelinePosition($('#anotherDiv'));

});
$('#targetSecondDiv').click(function() {
setTimelinePosition($('#testDiv'));

});

});


/* Show current position on timeline */
function setTimelinePosition($position) {


var $theTimelineTrigger = $('span.timelineTrigger');

toDoCategories.forEach(function(currentCategory) {


var $deselectTimelinePositionElement = $(currentCategory, $theTimelineTrigger);

$($deselectTimelinePositionElement).removeClass('currentPosition');
});
```

Comment: You're missing a `#` in the thirdDiv selector, and this entire approach is horrible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NWmB5/8/

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. Whilst this code is only for an HTML prototype (and isn't going near production without a proper Developer rewriting most of it) I'd like to make it less "horrible".

I think a sensible thing would be to apply a common class to all of the divs with the IDs which I later place in the array and use it to generate the array. I'd appreciate any tips you might have to make the developers less offended by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $toDoCategories = $("#testDiv, #anotherDiv, #thirdDiv"); //NOTE HERE

    setTimelinePosition('#thirdDiv');

    $('#targetFirstDiv').click(function () {
        setTimelinePosition('#anotherDiv');
    });
    $('#targetSecondDiv').click(function () {
        setTimelinePosition('#testDiv');
    });

    /* Show current position on timeline */
    function setTimelinePosition(position) {
        $toDoCategories.find('.currentPosition').removeClass('currentPosition')
        $(position).find('.timelineTrigger').addClass('currentPosition');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BKjm4/)

---

Another approach: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BKjm4/3/)

Comment: Thanks Arun. I'll have a go with the second approach you recommended.